# Can the .git folder be used for backup and restoring?

Tags: backup, git

Seeing as [git's book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) says that git keeps, as they call it, a database of all the snapshots of changes, does this mean that I can use `.git` for reliably backing up my code? That is, can I only back up my (local) `.git` directory to a cloud for example, and then if at any point I lose my entire hard disk, presumably I would be able to download the `.git` folder from the backup on my cloud, and from that I could restore all the source code files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that would work. You can check this yourself by copying the `.git` folder to another directory, open Terminal / Command Prompt, navigate to that folder and execute

```
git checkout -- *
```

The repository will be completely restored to the last committed version.